# T-SQL Cursor with multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables:

- `Customer` [customer Id, company, city]
- `Person` [Id, City, Pay, Name]
- `Warehouse` [ProductID, Name, City, Price]

Using T-SQL cursor, I need to create a new table with columns `CITY`, `NUMBER OF CUSTOMERS`, `NUMBER OF PRODUCTS` and `NUMBER OF PERSONS`.

Goal is to produce a table (shown below) that shows all the cities, count all the customers in specific city and do the same for products and persons.

```
City | Number of Customers | Number of Products | Number of Persons | 
-----+---------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
NYC  |        4            |        2           |        2          |     
LA   |        0            |        4           |        0          |     
DAL  |        1            |        0           |        1          |
```

I have tough time really understanding how the cursor works due to my retardation...

This is what I have tried:

```sql
DECLARE @CUSTOMERID INT,
        @CITY VARCHAR(100),
        @ID VARCHAR(500),
        @PRODUCTID INT,
        @ERROR INT,
        @ERRORTEXT NVARCHAR(1000)

DECLARE @NEWTABLE TABLE
                  (
                      CITY VARCHAR NOT NULL,
                      NUMBEROFCUSTOMERS INT,
                      NUMBEROFPRODUCTS INT, 
                      NUMBEROFPERSONS INT
                  );

DECLARE K CURSOR FOR
    SELECT C.CUSTOMERID, P.ID, W.PRODUCTID, P.CITY
    FROM dbo.CUSTOMER AS C 
    INNER JOIN PERSON AS P ON C.POSTITP = P.CITY
    INNER JOIN WAREHOUSE AS W ON P.CITY = W.CITY
    
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY
    
    OPEN K

    WHILE 1=1
    BEGIN
      IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
      BEGIN
        BREAK
      END
    
      FETCH NEXT FROM K INTO @NEWTABLE
    END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    
    SET @ERROR = ERROR_NUMBER()
    SET @ERRORTEXT = ERROR_MESSAGE()
    PRINT 'ERROR ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),@ERROR) + ': ' + @ERRORTEXT
END CATCH

IF CURSOR_STATUS('GLOBAL','K') >= 0
BEGIN
    CLOSE K
    DEALLOCATE K
END

END
GO
```

Comment: One of the first questions I have is why use a `CURSOR`? SQL is a set based language, so a iterative process is going to be the slowest way of proceasing your data by far. Sample data and expected breaults will help us help you, as I very much expect you've gone down the wrong rabbit hole here.

Comment: I am aware that it is not the optimal nor the best solution, and I doubt I would ever use it myself,but  Im trying to gain understanding on how it works with multiple tables and how to implement with this example.

Answer (score 2):

Your goal is to get that result as a new table, no? Why do you think you need a cursor?

```
Select coalesce(c.City, w.City, p.City) City,
    c.Cnt [Number of Customers],
    w.Cnt [Number of Products],
    p.Cnt [Number of Persons]
into myNewTable
from     
(Select city, Count(*) Cnt from Customer group by City) c
full join 
(Select city, Count(*) Cnt from Warehouse group by City) w
on c.City = w.City
full join 
(Select city, Count(*) Cnt from Person group by City) p on 
p.City = w.City or p.City = c.City; 

Select * from myNewTable;
```

EDIT: If you don't want a table all you need is to remove "into myNewTable":

```
Select coalesce(c.City, w.City, p.City) City,
    c.Cnt [Number of Customers],
    w.Cnt [Number of Products],
    p.Cnt [Number of Persons]
from     
(Select city, Count(*) Cnt from Customer group by City) c
full join 
(Select city, Count(*) Cnt from Warehouse group by City) w
on c.City = w.City
full join 
(Select city, Count(*) Cnt from Person group by City) p on 
p.City = w.City or p.City = c.City;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I don't want to create a new table, just get the results as table form

Comment: @Jkn, then simply remove the "into myNewTable" line and last select :)

Comment: Yeah,figured that out as soon as I wrote the question.. thanks though :) One thing I haven't figured out is, how in this query do I replace the null values with 0, if you create a new table, its pretty simple with ISNULL function, but is it possible to do the same without creating a new table, and referring to my original question, how would this query be done using the cursor ?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Check coalesce() for example. You should spare some time learning SQL.